# How to replace all NA values in numerical columns only with median values and update the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a data frame (imported from an csv file) which has NA values in its numerical columns. And I want to replace all of the NA values to median values and update the data frame. For example in this picture, the column "Speed_of_maximum_wind_gust(km/h)", which is a numerical column has an NA value (red circled) [image]

Then I went ahead and add the following code:

```
test2 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm = T), x))
```

The above code certainly works, however it only gave an output:
[image]

And the mentioned NA value remains the same:

[image]

I don't know what I did wrong here but I want the result to be updated in the data frame so that I can export it as new .csv file for later. Would anyone be able to help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue might be that you haven't actually saved the data frame anywhere (using e.g. `test2 <- test2 %>% mutate_if(...)`, but it's not clear from your post. What is the source of your third screenshot? Are you just going back into the viewer after you run the line of code you gave?

Comment: (Just a statistical comment - replacing missing values with averages is prone to introducing bias, do it with care!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, it looks like you're just going back to the RStudio viewer window to look at the data frame again. If so, the issue is this:

When you write `test2 %>% mutate_if(...)`, you're telling R to change something in `test2` and *return* the result (roughly meaning, in this context, to just print the result and show it to you). What you're *not* telling it to do is to *save* that result anywhere.

You would want something like `test2 <- test2 %>% mutate_if(...)` to overwrite the existing `test2` data frame in your global environment, or something like `test3 <- test2 %>% mutate_if(...)` to give it a new name and store the modified thing as a separate object while retaining the old one.

Lastly, I would echo Andrea M's concern that you might not want to do this at all. Imputing missing data with averages is, on a *good* day, risky.

Comment: I got it to work, sorry I'm new to R programming and I forgot I need to assign that back to test2 to override the existing data. That was silly of me. In regards to Andrea M' concern, would you be able to explain to me as to why replacing NA values with median is not recommended? Thank you!

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to *do* with them, but imputing median values will have side effects such as reducing the overall variance of your variable. Additionally, if the entries with missing variables have any particular communality, you might introduce bias by making this replacement. (Those are the first two reasons that came to mind; there are others.) In generally, it's safer to *remove* missing values than to fill them in -- but depending on how many there are, this too may be problematic.

Comment: I was doing practices of my own in R and came at a part where I need to replace NA values. They weren't very thorough with their explanation but I understand it better with yours. Thanks a lot!